# Does it make sense to run scrapy/selenium script on AWS?

Tags: selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

I am currently scraping a super slow website. Therefore, I already bought a windows2000 virtual machine. However, this machine is using a static IP. As a result, I got banned.

Now, I am wondering if it would make sense to move my script (Scrapy, Selenium and Chrome) to AWS.

Has anybody experiences in using AWS for crawling? What is the typical price for it?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need a different machine, you need a proxy. Or even better, a [smart proxy](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera).